# On Mac Big Sur, how do I downgrade my version of Unision to a specific version?

Tags: version, macos-big-sur, unison

I’m running Mac OS 11.5.2 (Big Sur).  I have the following version of unison installed using

```
brew install unison
```

Which is

```
$ unison -version
unison version 2.51.4 (ocaml 4.12.0)
```

However, in order to work with a virtual Ubuntu box, which runs

```
$ unison -version
unison version 2.51.2 (ocaml 4.08.1)
```

I need to downgrade my Mac OS version of Unison.  But the brew command doesn’t give me control over the version.  How do I downgrade my Mac version to match the Linux version?

Comment: I think this question is not programming related and might find answer on superuser

Answer (score 1):

modify Unison's Formula code from this url
[Unison Formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/unison.rb) and copy that
then run command like that

```
# copy formula code
pbpaste > $(find $(brew --repository) -name unison.rb)
brew install unison
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# copy formula code
pbpaste > $(find $(brew --repository) -name <FORMULA>.rb)
brew install <FORMULA>
```

follow this blog https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/02/03/install-brew-package-version/

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not finding the formula for unision v 2.51.2 for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

`Brew` is a [rolling release](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues/118) package manager, which more or less by design does not let/want you to access previous versions.

If ditching brew is okay for you.

You can go directly to [Unison's Github](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison). On there you will be able to download the release you want [Unison version 2.51.2 for OSX](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/releases/download/v2.51.2/Unison-2.51.2.OS.X.zip)

Install should be very standard, unzip the file, drag the `.app` file to your application folder.